# How to do to I get the text from the style of span in Protractor?

Tags: protractor

How do I get the text from the style of span in Protractor.

For example:

```
<span class="tg-std-row" style >Hello world </span>
```

I want the text as 'Hello world'

Comment: You're asking about the `innerHTML` from the sound of it. There is no style attached to your element.

Comment: Try to be more specific and less confusing, so people could help you faster and not guess what you actually need

Answer (score 0):

`element.getAttribute("style")` for getting text of style attribute
`element.getText()' for getting text inside the tag

Either way, question is too simple to require help, since you could easily find answers here https://www.protractortest.org/#/api